# In Dart, how do I let an overloaded operator return the subclass type?

Tags: dart, operator-overloading, subclass

I have two simple classes: `Point` (which has an x and y) and `Point3D` (which `extends Point` and also has a z parameter).  I want to override the + operator so that I can add two points. Because the + operator needs to return the class, the method signature for + in Point is different from the signature for + in Point3D, which is not allowed in Dart. I have tried it via an interface:

```
abstract class PointOperations<T extends Point> {
   T operator +(T p);
}
```

and implement this in Point and Point3D as follows:

```
class Point implements PointOperations<Point> {
  final double x, y;

  Point(this.x, this.y);
    
  @override
  Point operator +(Point p) => Point(x + p.x, y + p.y);
}

class Point3D extends Point implements PointOperations<Point3D>{
  final double z;

  Point3D(double x, double y, this.z) : super(x, y);

  @override
  Point3D operator +(Point3D p) => Point3D(x + p.x, y + p.y, z + p.z);
}
```

I get the compile error `The class 'Point3D' cannot implement both 'PointOperations<Point>' and 'PointOperations<Point3D>' because the type arguments are different.`  I understand that error, but don't understand how I can accomplish what I want without resorting to methods with distinct names (e.g. `Point addPoint(Point p)` and `Point3D addPoint3D(Point3D p)`).

I can get this to work using named constructors:

`Point.add(Point a, Point b) : x = a.x + b.x, y = a.y + b.y;`

and

`Point3D.add(Point3D a, Point3D b) : z = a.z + b.z, super(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);`

but this is not as elegant and certainly is not operator overloading.  Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Do you intend to allow a `Point` and `Point3D` to be added together?

Comment: No, that is not a use case I foresee. I just want to add `Point` to `Point` or `Point3D` to `Point3D` using the `operator +` overloading. The reason I want `Point3D` to extend `Point` is that the actual `Point` class has a lot of useful helper methods that are relevant to both classes. For example `toRightOf(Point p)` which works for both `Point` and `Point3D`

Comment: I could implement `Point` and `Point3D` as unrelated classes but then I lose those helper methods like `toRightOf` that I would then have to reimplement for `Point3D`, and those helpers are not different between `Point` and `Point3D`. I guess I could put those in a mixin and add that to both classes (now unrelated) but that seems backwards as I clearly am subclassing here

Comment: In that case, you might want to have `Point` and `Point3D` derive from some other common base class that provides the interface you *do* want to share and then let `Point` and `Point3D` implement `operator+` separately.  That base class could be `PointOperations` but without the `operator+` interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. In `Point` I define:

```
Point operator +(covariant Point p) => Point(x + p.x, y + p.y);
```

Defining the argument as a `covariant` is what allows the subclass to then use the argument `Point3D` without conflict. In `Point3D` I define:

```
@override
Point3D operator +(Point3D p) => Point3D(x + p.x, y + p.y, z + p.z);
```

The return type works as it's a subclass of `Point`.

Note it is possible to use the following alternative:

```
@override
Point3D operator +(Point p) => Point3D(x + p.x, y + p.y, z + (p as Point3D).z);
```

where requires you cast the `Point p` to access `z`, but which may be useful if one would want to add a `Point` to a `Point3D` (which would require extra type checks and is not what I am looking for, but one could imagine doing this and setting `z` to 0 if `p` is a `Point` and not `Point3D`).

Comment: Using `covariant` like this is exactly what it's intended for. It does introduce a run-time check which can be made to fail, like `Point p = Point3D(); p + Point();` which is statically valid and fails at run-time. 
(I'd probably just not make `Point3D` a subclass of `Point` at all, maybe let both inherit some base class with no special interface, if there is functionality which can be shared).